# I need to Generate barcode image with label in UPC A format on it in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[Sample UPC A Format image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gub5n.png)

I used Zxing libray.it's generating barcode image without label but i need with label as like attached image..

Code i used to generate image:

```
 Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

        Writer codeWriter;
        if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
            codeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        } else if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.CODE_128) {
            codeWriter = new Code128Writer();
        } else if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.UPC_A) {
            codeWriter = new UPCAWriter();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Format Not supported.");
        }

        BitMatrix byteMatrix = codeWriter.encode(
                codeData,
                barcodeFormat,
                codeWidth,
                codeHeight,
                hintMap
        );

        int width = byteMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = byteMatrix.getHeight();

        Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                imageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, byteMatrix.get(i, j) ? BLACK : Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

using below library you have to generate QRCode in android.This library is built on Zxing library.

https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

Android Code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap();
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

For barcode with lable use below code and also put core-3.0.1.jar zxing jar in lib folder:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BarcodeExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(l);

    // barcode data
    String barcode_data = "123456";

    // barcode image
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

    try {

        bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    l.addView(iv);

    //barcode text
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tv.setText(barcode_data);

    l.addView(tv);

    }

    /**************************************************************
     * getting from com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.QRCodeEncoder
     * 
     * See the sites below
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/EncodeActivity.java
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java
     */

    private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

    Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
    }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
    // Very crude at the moment
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
        if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
        return "UTF-8";
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this library is only for generating QR Code ?

Comment: using the above code iam able to see barcode image with label but it is not displaying like attached image.it is displaying entire label at the bottom of image